# Regex for inet addr failed

Tags: regex, linux, bash, ip, ifconfig

In Ubuntu 16.04 I ran `ifconfig` and saw my external ip as in `inet addr:MY_IP`.

I tried to "dug" it right into a variable in these ways:

```
ipa=$(ifconfig | grep "inet addr:\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b")
```

and:

```
ipa=$(ifconfig | grep "inet addr:\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.")
```

These methods work:

```
ipa=$(ifconfig | grep -Po 'inet addr:\K[^\s]+' | grep -v '^127')
```

and

```
ipa=$(ifconfig | grep -A 1 eth0 | grep -Po "inet addr:(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}" | cut -f2 -d:)
```

But I would like to know, please, what I've missed in my first 2 tryings.

### Update:

Is there a way to use one `grep` with 4 groups (similar to the concept of the first 2) that will indeed work in POSIX BRE?

Comment: POSIX BRE used in the first case does not support `\b` and `\d`, and `{...}` must be escaped. The seocnd one contains unescaped `(` and `)` and non-supported `\b` and only matches one octet.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I swear your comment was posted before the question.

Comment: @ctwheels POSIX BRE does not support `\K`. The third one is a PCRE regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew my bad, failed to see `P`

Comment: Even with `grep -E` first 2 commands won't work because it will match complete line instead of extracting IP address

Comment: Is there a way to use one `grep` with 4 groups (similar to the concept of the first 2) that will indeed work in POSIX BRE?

Comment: If you want to get internal IP then use `ip route get 4.4.4.4 | awk '{print $NF; exit}'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which terminal command to get just IP address and nothing else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529181/which-terminal-command-to-get-just-ip-address-and-nothing-else)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `\b` with the old-style `\<` though it doesn't seem to be POSIX.

Notice also that alternation `(a|b)` is a `grep -E` feature. In POSIX grep, you can backslash those constructs (weirdly) but I'd just go with `grep -E`.

```
ipa=$(ifconfig | grep -E "inet addr:\<(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.")
```

There is no need for a word boundary there, though; you already know the character to the left is a colon and the one to the right is a digit.