# How to match ip address

Tags: python

I'm trying to match ip address using ip address that i input myself and ip address that grep using os on python, but when i run my code, the code say not match

```
app = Tk()
app.title('IP Address')
app.geometry('250x150+200+200')
b = StringVar()

ip = os.popen("ip -4 addr show wlan0 | grep -oP '(?<=inet\s)\d+(\.\d+){3}'").read()
#this will insert wlan0 ip address to variable ip
print(ip)

def com():
        c = b.get()
        if c == ip:
                labl3 = Label(text='Match').pack()
                app.destroy()
        else:
                labl3 = Label(text='Not Match').pack()

labl1 = Label(text='Input Ip address',font=30).pack()

text = Entry(textvariable=b).pack()

button1 = Button(text='Press to print', command= com).pack()

app.mainloop()
```

how i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using python3, there is an [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) module. One would use it as follows:

```
if ipaddress.ip_address(str(lab1)): # valid ip
    pass # or whatever
else:
    raise Exception('Invalid ip address')
```

If you're using python2, there's a [backport](https://pypi.org/project/backport_ipaddress/). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

`c == ip` will only evaluate true if the two strings are exactly equal, character for character.

It is likely that this is not evaluating to true because the `ip` has some trailing white-space characters (in fact, I just ran the command, and it does indeed include a trailing new-line character).

You should therefore compare them like this instead: `c.strip() == ip.strip()`

the `.strip()` method removes all trailing and leading whitespace in a given string. The above command is therefore comparing the trailing/leading whitespace removed versions of the strings.

---

Tip: if you want to debug something like this in future, check `len(c)` and `len(ip)` and see if they are the same length.

Comment: when i change c = b.get to c.strip() = b.get().strip() ,the code become error SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Comment: To clarify, what you should do is replace the if condition in your code: `if c == ip` to `if c.strip() == ip.strip()`

Comment: when i change ip at def com() to string like '192.168.0.1' and i ran it, i type same ip address it say match and destroy the window

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by modifying your regex

```
pat = re.compile("^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$")
```

its because `.` is a wildcard that stands for "every character" .

Comment: Don't use regexps unnecessarily

Comment: I don't see why not, especially if the OP did not indicate that they would rather not use regex. This is a valid solution imo.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of questions to get started.

I'm assuming you are running this on a *nix machine because of the use of  the `ip` command, unless you have installed `iproute2mac` for mac or on linux for windows. Could you tell us what platform you are running on? Also, can you tell me the output of the command `ip -4 addr show` (please omit any details you don't want to share online). Besides platform related things, it could be an issue with string trimming or character escaping. If you could provide a print debug of the inputs that would be super helpful as well.

Thanks!

Comment: im using raspberry pi and found that command on (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529181/which-terminal-command-to-get-just-ip-address-and-nothing-else)