# Only get the first part of grep: get ip of ifconfig

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, ifconfig

```
ifconfig | grep -m1 "inet addr"
```

Gives me

```
inet addr:172.30.1.6  Bcast:172.30.140.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
```

However, I only want the ip, which is `172.30.1.6`. How can I do this?
Note that I have to be using ifconfig, as this is an embedded system with limited functionalities.

Comment: There are several *nix utilities to process that line one you have it... `cut`, `sed` etc.

Comment: *"... I have to be using ifconfig ..."* - Good luck on Fedora and others, where `ifconfig` is gone and you have to use the 
`ip` utility.

Answer (score 5):

Get out your scissors, it's cuttin' time.

```
echo inet addr:172.30.1.6  Bcast:172.30.140.255  Mask:255.255.252.0 | cut -d : -f 2 | cut -d " " -f 1
```

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it ..

```
ifconfig | grep -m1 "inet addr" | awk '{print $2}' | awk -F: '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 4):

If all you want to do is obtain the ip address, there might be easier ways of achieving that using say **hostname -i** ( reference [Which terminal command to get just IP address and nothing else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529181/which-terminal-command-to-get-just-ip-address-and-nothing-else) )

Since others have mentioned cut and awk, I will provide a solution using sed :

```
echo "inet addr:172.30.1.6  Bcast:172.30.140.255  Mask:255.255.252.0" | sed -e "s/.*\(addr:[^ ]*\) .*/\1/"

addr:172.30.1.6

echo "inet addr:172.30.1.6  Bcast:172.30.140.255  Mask:255.255.252.0" | sed -e "s/.*addr:\([^ ]*\) .*/\1/" 

172.30.1.6
```

Comment: hooray for `sed`!

Answer (score 2):

Use cut with a delimiter

```
| cut -d':' -f 2 | cut -d' ' -f 1
```

Comment: This gives everything _before_ the first colon, which is `inet addr`

Comment: Same here @StephenP

Comment: You just need two cuts, see my answer.

Comment: Thats what I get for typing on the phone.  edited to -f 2

Answer (score 2):

Is this all you're trying to do?

```
awk -F'[: ]' '/inet addr/{print $3; exit}'
```

For example using `cat file` in place of `ifconfig`:

```
$ cat file
inet addr:172.30.1.6  Bcast:172.30.140.255  Mask:255.255.252.0

$ cat file | awk -F'[: ]' '/inet addr/{print $3; exit}'
172.30.1.6
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it with a single `sed` command, eliminating the call to `grep`:

```
ifconfig | sed -n '/inet addr/{s/^.*inet addr:\([^ ]*\).*$/\1/p;q}'
```

There are a few things going on here:

- `sed -n` tells `sed` not to print every line like it normally does
- `/inet addr/` is a `sed` address - it tells `sed` to only operate on lines containing `"inet addr"`
- The `{` and `}` brackets define a block of commands to be run, with the commands separated by a `;`
- The `s` command is fairly straightforward - it just captures the IP and replaces the whole line with just the IP
- The `p` *flag* at the end of the `s` command tells `sed` to print the result of the substitution. This is necessary because we called `sed` with the `-n` option.
- The `q` command tells `sed` to quit, so that it only processes the *first* line containing `"inet addr"`.

Using the `-n` option, the `/inet addr/` address, the `p` flag on the `s` command, and the `q` command, essentially has the same effect as `grep -m1 "inet addr"`, which makes calling `grep` unnecessary. In fact, it's worth noting that the following commands produce identical output:

```
> ifconfig | grep -m1 "inet addr"
         inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

> ifconfig | sed -n '/inet addr/{p;q}'
         inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

Here, I've omitted the `s/pattern/replacement/p` part of the `sed` command, and replaced it with a `p` command (which just prints the whole line), just to show the effect of the other parts in isolation.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the command **cut**.

```
ip a | grep -m1 "inet addr" | cut -d':' -f 2 | cut -d' ' -f 1
```

I also advise you to learn the use of other commands such as : **wc,sed,tr,sort,uniq**. They will help manipulate the output as you please. Here is a small lesson where we present you all these command : https://www.javatpoint.com/linux-filters

I hope to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Using Bash's regex operator `=~`:

```
$ [[ $(ifconfig | grep -m1 "inet addr") =~ [0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
172.30.1.6
```

**Update**: Something even better in the comments.

Comment: I like the idea of doing as much as possible in pure `bash` instead of relying on `awk`, `sed`, `cut`, et. al., but why not get rid of the `grep` as well? `[[ $(ifconfig) =~ inet\ addr:([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+) ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`