# How can I retrieve my host machines IP address from inside a docker compose file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've looked at many stackoverflow answers but couldn't find a solution to my problem, so I apologise if it seems similar to other questions.
I have a docker compose file which needs to connect to a local database sitting on port 5555. I need to be able to set an env var in the docker compose file that will translate to my host machines IP address.
Something like

```
environment:
  - db_uri=postgres://(HOST_IP):5555/db_name
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You'd need to set the environment variable outside Docker Compose space, but the linked question discusses the standard ways to find it.  On non-Linux host Docker provides a DNS name for you.  I'd avoid host networking if you can (for all the top answer to that question promotes it), it disables many of the standard Docker features.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create two containers with the same network, then you can call the database URL directly.

refers:
`https://runnable.com/docker/docker-compose-networking`

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in 2 steps -

1. Define HOST_IP as a variable in the docker compose file, 
   using the ${} notation as follows:

> db_uri=postgres://${HOST_IP}:5555/db_name

2. Pass the dynamic variable - HOST_IP to compose file, either through ***.env*** file in the same directory or through ***export*** command.

**.env file example:**

> HOST_IP=192.168.1.100

**export command example:**

> export HOST_IP=192.168.1.100

**More information:**

**Dynamic variables in docker compose file:**
https://serversforhackers.com/c/div-variables-in-docker-compose

**Get the IP address of a host:**

[Which terminal command to get just IP address and nothing else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529181/which-terminal-command-to-get-just-ip-address-and-nothing-else/26694162#26694162)

Comment: This would work, however I'm looking for a way to be able to find the HOST_IP on whatever machine I'm using, so I don't want to hard code the IP address because then it could potentially change on every machine

Comment: Hi Oliver, Please refer the link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529181/which-terminal-command-to-get-just-ip-address-and-nothing-else/26694162#26694162 for details on finding IP address on all hosts.